# On the symmetry (and anti-symmetry) of operators in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

In quantum mechanics, the terms symmetric and antisymmetric typically refer to states; specifically, a state is said to be '(anti)symmetric' if it is an eigenstate of the exchange operator with an eigenvalue of (-)1. Does it make sense to attribute these two categories to operators as well?
For example, in what sense is $p^\mu p^\nu$ said to be symmetric? ($p^\mu = i\hbar\partial^\mu$ being the four-momentum operator)

Comment: So you want us to create a definition for symmetry of operators or do you want to understand an already given definition? if it is the latter please provide a reference.

Comment: Observables on the $N$-particle space of identical fermions or bosons should obey $PAP=A$ for all permutation operators $P$.

Comment: In the sense an operator flanked by exchange operators is minus itself. You may think of an operator as a dyadic.

Comment: $p^\mu p^\nu=p^\nu p^\mu$, means symmetric under interchange of indices, which define your state, hence operator basis.

Comment: There is a relatively artificial sense in which you can talk about operators being anti-symmetric e.g. let $X_{\mu\nu}:=[A_\mu,B_\nu]$. This is an array of operators though and perhaps not what you had in mind.